# search start/end of word with ripgrep

Tags: ripgrep

With `grep` I can search for the start and end of a word with

```
grep -e '\<leg\>' <where to search>
```

this would find `I have a leg.` but not `play allegro here`.

Ripgrep (0.10.0) does not seem to support this way of writing this regular expression. My question thus is:

How to "grep" for occurrences at the begin/end of a word with `ripgrep`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

ripgrep doesn't support the `\<` and `\>` word boundaries, which specifically only match the start and end of a word, respectively. ripgrep does however support `\b`, which matches a word boundary anywhere. In this case, it's good enough for your specific example:

```
$ echo 'play allegro here' | rg '\bleg\b'
$ echo 'I have a leg.' | rg '\bleg\b'
I have a leg.
```

ripgrep also supports grep's `-w` flag, which effectively does the same thing in this case:

```
$ echo 'play allegro here' | rg -w leg
$ echo 'I have a leg.' | rg -w leg
I have a leg.
```